# Why does one have to repeat the const specifier at definition time, if declaration as const is done somewhere else?

Tags: c++, static, constants, declaration, definition

After solving [this simple issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36687185/c-11-initialize-static-const-class-member/36687980#36687980), I had to ask :

-> In the H file in a class ex a const static member is defined, e.g. :

```
class ex {
    const static int my_ex;
};
```

-> In the CPP file the value is specified

```
ex::my_ex = 32;
```

And then one gets the error "conflicting declarations" (as well as "does not name a type"). I understand that the *definition* in the CPP file is also a *declaration* which does create a conflict seen from the linker BUT why only about the *const* specifier (and type) and not the *static* one ? I only have to write

```
const int ex::my_ex = 32;
```

to get it to compile. But not static ... Why not? Why can't I just *define* and not repeat *declaration* related steps (type, specific identifiers)?

Comment: `static` never is used for definitions.

Comment: Ok... but **why**  is really my question ...

Comment: Static in declaration and static in definition mean different thing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is not technically correct. `struct X { static const int x = 42; };`

Comment: Everything typed entity has precisely one type. You can't specify different types for the same entity at different times. `static` is different because it's not part of the type.

Comment: @SergeyA OK, inline definitions aside.

Comment: @SergeyA: That's not a definition. That's a declaration and an initializer.

Comment: @SergeyA Correct actually, but it doesn't really answer the question. If they decided to not force the writer to rewrite the word static, then they could also have done the same for the word const ...

Comment: The question is really not very different from why you can't declare `extern int a; extern char a;`

Comment: You're all answering a little fast, would someone sum up definition vs. declaration vs. initialization vs. type-related keywords vs. other keywords vs. meaning of keywords depending on context ? That'd be great.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for a description of how C++ works. Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: You're either asking why `const` needs to be given again, or why `static` _doesn't_. (Or why there's an inconsistency.) Which is it? And why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, I was wrong. But in a more correct example with static member function with inline definition static would still be used for definition.

Comment: "Why can't I just define and not repeat declaration related steps" — in my opinion, repeating specifiers is useful: reading a code is more convenient, you have more important information about members without opening a header. But it's somewhat inconsistent that you can't put static for a definition bc of contradicting with another semantics.

Answer (score 9):

This is a historical thing.

Since C, `static` on a definition means "internal linkage". When C++ came along, and classes were added to it, Bjarne needed a keyword to signify static members. Not wanting to add new keywords (a preference that largely exists still to this day), he re-used `static` instead.

Now `static` meant two different things depending on where you put it. So you *can't* write `static` here because it would mean something else. Thus, the language doesn't require you to, as that would be silly.

Beyond that reasoning, *it just is*. When you create a language, you balance simplicity of specification against simplicity of implementation against simplicity of use, and you come up with a set of rules that are the language. At some point you have to stop quibbling over "why" some insignificant rule was created and just get on with writing your program.